# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line 13

Tags: php, string, parsing, constants

I cannot for the life of me figure out what this error is, I say it's something simple, and if so, my apologies! But I am literally about the pull my hair out.

```
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>

<div id="loop" class="list clear" class="news-archive">
<ul>

<?php $post_org = $post; ?>
<?php query_posts( 'cat=-13,-10,-1,-22&posts_per_page=10&paged='.$paged' ); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<li>
    <div <?php post_class('post clear'); ?> id="news-archive-wrapper" class="news-archive-wrapper" >

        <div class="news-archive-date"><p><?php the_time('M jS') ?></p></div>

      <div class="news-archive-content"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p>
<?php
  $excerpt = get_the_title();
  echo string_limit_words($excerpt,15);
 ?>...</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>


</ul> 

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where is endwhile; after li closed? and why endif; at last of page?

Answer (score 0):

On line 7 (of your excerpt), you're adding a ' too much

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=-13,-10,-1,-22&posts_per_page=10&paged='.$paged ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just found that too! Also missing <?php endwhile; ?> near the end too! Thank god!